# Django have defined a model but the model's some field doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am using Django 2.2, MySQL 8.0. When I define a model, I create some class properties and their fields. After saving the operation, PyCharm did not report an error.

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField
class Activity(models.Model):
    sponsor               = models.IntegerField
    certificateOrNot      = models.BooleanField
    sponsorWay            = models.SmallIntegerField
    activityName          = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    activityPhoto         = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    prizeInfo             = JsonField
    activityDetails       = models.IntegerField
    startTime             = models.DateField
    endTime               = models.DateField
    conditionType         = models.SmallIntegerField
    conditionInfo         = models.SmallIntegerField
    sponsorPhoneNumber    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sponsorNickName       = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    sponsorWechatNumber   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    participantAttention  = models.BooleanField
    shareJurisdiction     = models.BooleanField
    allowQuitOrNot        = models.BooleanField
    inviateFriends        = models.BooleanField
    inputCommandOrNot     = models.BooleanField
    participateWay        = models.BooleanField
    winnerList            = models.BooleanField
    participantDrawNumber = models.SmallIntegerField

def __str__(self):
    return self.activityName
```

Then I synchronize the database.

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations luckyDraw_1
python3 manage.py migrate
```

At this point MySQL can successfully create the table, but the fields in the table do not meet my expectations.

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| activityName        | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activityPhoto       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sponsorPhoneNumber  | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sponsorNickName     | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sponsorWechatNumber | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So,what's the problem?

Comment: Make an instance of each field, not just of those where you want to pass arguments -- `winnerList = models.BooleanField()` and so on. The parens are missing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. In my understanding, the properties of the class only correspond to the fields in MySQL, and models.xxxField is the field type in MySQL. Maybe the distance you are talking about is the models class property I understand? Can you answer my question again?

Comment: You are missing `( )` behind all the fields, except the ones that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fields are missing in your database table because you are missing parentheses on some fields in the end for example the first field should be `sponsor = models.IntegerField()` not `sponsor = models.IntegerField`

Comment: Yes, I just debugged it out.Thank you！